# WooCommerce API - change email from order

Tags: python, api, woocommerce

I would Like to update an orders billing email address in python.

this is what I have:

```
data = "{ 'billing' : { 'email': 'Jamesemail@asda.de' } }";
r = requests.put(api_url+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/"+str(id)+"?consumer_key="+api_key+"&consumer_secret="+api_pw,data) 
json_string = json.dumps(r.json())
data= json.loads(json_string)
print(data)
print(r)
```

I get a response code 200, but when I look at the data, it is not updated.
with other fields like status this works.

any idea is appriciated.
elenio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are sending isn't valid JSON. Strings in JSON should use double quotes `"`

Also consider using a python dictionary and the `json` kwarg instead of a JSON string if that option is available to you.

```py
requests.put(url, json={"billing": {'email': email}})
```

requests handles that appropriately even if you use a mix of double and single quotes like above (for some reason).